# individually hiding drop-downs according to one child-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've painfully got multiple drop-downs toggling states(hidden and shown) in JQuery but I have some code which tells the side bar which page is active and gives it the style active and I would like a drop down to not be hidden if there is a child active in it.

The top level link which you click to view the drop-down gets given the id "HAC"(has active child) if it has an active child but I think I might be burning my brain out on this.

[Here's a jsfiddle page with the working demo of the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/GaAk8/6/)

the drop down is set out like this in a nav

```
<ul id="HAC" class='topLevel'>                
   <li class='subItem'>
       <a class="active" href='thatpage.php'>That page</a>
   </li>
   <li class='subItem'>
       <a href='thatotherpage.php'>That other page</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: DO not duplicate the ids...

Comment: @PSL I'm not, here is only one dropdown with HAC.... and I would like it to Not hide it

Comment: oh you mean on the jsfiddle page, that's a mistake from pasting it in, It technically gets generated on php but it is not the problem

Comment: Your issue is unclear... Can you rephrase?

Comment: The problem was that every submenu should hide expect for the drop down an active child(the parent menu item is given the id HAC), @ethorn10 answered it and you can see how it is supposed to work on the jsfiddle he linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [jQuery :not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). Here is [an update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaAk8/9/)

```
function dropDowns() {
    //for each toplevel li a
    $(".topLevel:not(#HAC) li a").each(function() {
        //hide subitems if not HAC (has active children)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    //Toggle show them on click
    clickToggle();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was so stuck on the inner code I forgot that I could make the selection up on the each